# How can I allow users to access the settings menu in their devices to add a printer

Tags: google-chrome, admin, google-apps, google-workspace, google-chrome-os

Students can't access the settings menu in their devices to add a printer option.

Change the settings under Admin Console under Devices Chrome Settings but printer option is already allowed?

I'm assuming that it has to do something with the policy under each OU ( orgnaizational Unit )

I tried changing the setting for the Printer under Users & browser settings.

Menu devices then printer settings under Managed Printer, but its still not letting the students access settings for each device.

Now if I tried adding a printer under the admin console the users can't still see the printer and won't be able to choose a printer when they try to print something.

Can someone help me here, I just want the user to be able to access settings on their devices and be able to add a printer.

Comment: This question might better fit [webmasters.se] or [sf].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION

Have you tried doing this step?

Go to the [Admin console](https://admin.google.com/) and go to **Devices** > **Chrome** > **Settings**.

From there, make sure that you select the correct organizational unit and look for **Disabled system features**. Afterwards, make sure that **OS settings** is unchecked.

Once you do that, reload the policy for your users by going to **chrome://policy**

### REFERENCE

- [Set Chrome policies for users or browsers](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289#zippy=%2Cdisabled-system-features)